# PATH Environment Variable in Custom Python Environment in Visual Studio Altered

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, visual-studio-2017

I have a custom Python environment set in Visual Studio for ActivePython. However, it doesn't have access to the system PATH variable. When I type this in the Visual Studio Python Interactive:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH']
```

I get:

```
';C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pypiwin32_system32'
```

It is messing up my Python projects. However, when I use a different environment, it displays the full PATH. It also works fine using the environment outside Visual Studio.

How could I have this Python environment have full access to PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Python Tools -> General -> Ignore system-wide PYTHONPATH variables